# Understanding long passwords

Tags: probability

Let's say you have a PIN that is four digits long. Each digits can be 0 to 9 giving you a total of 10 possible digits. 
How many different PINs are possible??

Comment: A Pin is a number right ? How many numbers are they between 0 and 9999 ?

Comment: why the down vote on the question? It's a relevant question, and it shows the questioners attempts to start it.

Comment: What attempts of the OPs do you see, @Andrew?  I see nothing but a problem statement.

Comment: @amWhy - he's got as far as deducing that 0-9 represents 10 states

Comment: Pleeeaaase @Andrew that's part of what was already given...The problem wouldn't make sense if it were not to have a description of valid characters for the pin...nor how many options...  Anyway...that's like saying that an OP put in effort when asking what $1+2$ is equal to, because the OP noted that it must be some number which $1$, $2$ sum to.

Answer (score 2):

You have like you said $10$ choices for the first digit, $10$ for the second...

So

$$10\times 10\times 10\times 10=10\, 000$$

different PIN.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method of working this out is to not even use probability theory.

The combinations are:
$$
0000 \\
0001 \\
0002 \\
0003 \\
\vdots \\ 9999
$$

which is quite clearly 10000 options. It is literally counting from 0 to 9999 which is equivalent to counting from 1 to 10000. so 10000...